# Con un procedimiento almacenado, cómo pasar datos a dos tablas al mismo tiempo?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2019

tengo un procedimiento almacenado para agregar datos a dos tablas diferente, tabla **INVENTARIO** Y tabla **PRODUCTO**, Con el procedimiento almacenado mas abajo logro agregar los datos de la tabla **PRODUCTO**, y pero no logro agregar los datos en la otra tabla INVENTARIO. Ver si me pueden ayudar.

**TABLAS**

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTOS(
    idProducto int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    nombre varchar(100),
    descripcion varchar(255),
    idCategoria int, 
    precio decimal(11,2),
    stock int,
    estado bit default(1),

    FOREIGN KEY (idCategoria) REFERENCES CATEGORIA (idCategoria),
);

CREATE TABLE INVENTARIO(

    idInventario int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    fecha datetime NULL,
    razon varchar(200) NULL,
    cantidad numeric(18, 0) NULL,
    id_Producto int,
    activo varchar(50) NULL,
    hay numeric(18, 2) NULL,
    habia numeric(18, 2) NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (id_Producto) REFERENCES PRODUCTO (idProducto),

);
```

AQUI EL PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO

```
> create proc PRODUCTO_Guardar
    @nombre varchar(100),
    @descripcion varchar(255),
    @idCategoria int,
    @precio(11,2),
    @stock int,
    @estado bit,
    --datos tabla INVENTARIO
    @fecha datetime,
    @razon varchar(200),
    @cantidad int,
    @activo varchar(50)
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @id_Producto int
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS VALUES (@nombre,@descripcion,@idCategoria,@precio,@stock,@estado
         )
         SELECT  @id_Producto = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        
         DECLARE @hay AS numeric(18,2)
         DECLARE @habia as numeric(18,2)
        
       SET @hay = (SELECT stock  FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PRODUCTOS.idProducto = @id_Producto)
       SET @habia = @hay    
       
    INSERT INTO INVENTARIO VALUES 
    (@fecha, @razon, @cantidad, @activo, @id_Producto, @hay, @habia)        
END
```

AQUI EN LA CAPA DATOS

```
   public string Guardar(EProducto Obj)
        {
            string Rpta = "";
            try
            {
                Conexion.ConnectionString = PVDConexion.conectar;
                SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand("PRODUCTO_Guardar", Conexion);
                Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("@nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Obj.Nombre;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("@descripcion", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Obj.Descripcion;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("@idCategoria", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Obj.IdCategoria;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("@precioCompra", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Obj.PrecioCompra;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("@precioVenta", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Obj.PrecioVenta;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("@precioPorMayor", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Obj.PrecioPorMayor;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("@stock", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Obj.Stock;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("@estado", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Obj.Estado;
                //INVENTARIO
                Comando.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Obj.Fecha;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("@razon", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Obj.Razon;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("@cantidad", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Obj.Cantidad;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("@activo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Obj.Activo;
                Conexion.Open();
                Rpta = Comando.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "OK" : "No se pudo ingresar el registro";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Rpta = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (Conexion.State == ConnectionState.Open) Conexion.Close();
            }
            return Rpta;
        }
```

Agrego una aplicacion de ejemplo [Aplicacion](https://mega.nz/file/AEE3wRZb#xur5-MjC1tQOuEjQ2flvKxoQRlC_Qy-hRjyOcELPxaA)

Comment: ¿Qué versión de SQL Server? ¿Algún mensaje de error al ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: @Alfabravo la version osea el año 2019, no me da error, en C# paso todo, solo me registra la tabla producto, pero no la inventario. Gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué pones el mismo valor en hay y habia? ¿Qué pasa si ya existe el producto? ¿Como determinas que un producto ya existe?

Comment: Te toca incluir el problema que tienes al invocar el SP desde C#. Y el código correspondiente. Hasta ahora nadie sabe qué error tienes ni en dónde y estás poniendo a la gente a adivinar.

Comment: si asi lo he hecho al final agregue una aplicacion previa

Comment: Pregunta autocontenida. El enlace vence y la pregunta es inútil para la comunidad. Añáde el código relevante, donde llamas el SP, no es complicado; en cambio, nadie se va a sentar a leer TODA la aplicación

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias por tu tiempo dedicado, valoro eso,al final agrege un elance de una pequeña aplicacionque hice para ver si me pueden ayudar

Comment: El llamado al SP en C# tiene 12 parámetros y el SP sólo usa 10. ¿Seguro que eso no te muestra alguna excepción?

Comment: @Alfabravo y a los demas muchas gracias a parte de ese problema estuve otro que pude notar luego, estaba dando una referencia a la tabla PRODUCTO y tenia que ser PRODUCTOS osea le faltaba una (S)

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza desde **SELECT @id_producto = SCOPE_IDENTITY()** por lo sguiente :

```
SET @id_Producto = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
DECLARE @hay int, @habia int
SELECT @hay = stock, @habia = stock FROM PRODUCTOS
WHERE IdProducto = @id_Producto
INSERT INTO INVENTARIO VALUES (@fecha,@razon,@cantidad,@id_producto,@activo,@hay,@habia)
```

Comment: Hola @Jorge Leiva, voy a verificar, te comento

Comment: Incluso se puede refactorizar mas aun escribiendo solamente el SET @id_producto = SCOPE_IDENTIRY()

Comment: y luego el INSERT INTO INVENTARIO (@fecha,@razon,@cantidad,@id_producto,@activo,@stock,@stock)

Comment: @JorgeLeiva prueba yendo a [edit] la respuesta y complementando, en vez de poner código en los comentarios ;)

Comment: En verdad todo funciona bien en SQL server, creo que el problema lo tengo en el codigo C# por lo que veo

Comment: @AlfaBravo, disculpa mi mala educación pero soy un recién llegado a este sitio y aun no tengo muy claro las reglas de comportamiento pero ya aprenderé.

Answer (score 0):

¿Te marca algún error? ¿Cuál es el error que te marca después de ejecutar el SP?

De entrada te digo que para insertar datos a la tabla INVENTARIO ocupas especificar los campos, ya que tiene un campo IDENTITY y este se debe omitir:

```
INSERT INTO INVENTARIO (fecha, razon, cantidad, id_producto, activo, hay, habia)
VALUES (@fecha, @razon, @cantidad, @id_Producto, @activo, @hay, @habia)
```

Comment: no me realiza ningun error todo pasa bien con el procedimiento almacenado